# jaxb - generate classes from single schema in different packages depending on namespace

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

My requirement is that I have a very big schema and it has many different tags with different namespaces. I want to generate classes from that schema into different packages and I want this thing to be bases on namespace i.e. I want classes corresponding to tags in one namespace to be in one package and classes corresponding to tags in other namespace to be present in different name space. 
I want an ant task to perform the above functionality

Comment: Please post an example, including your schema's namespace declaration and example elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is normal JAXB behaviour: XJC derives packages from namespace URIs (`http://www.acme.com/foo` -> `com.acme.foo`).

Here's a sample Ant "Purchase Order" project:

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Downloads